# Running javascript function when option selected

Tags: javascript, html, menu, html-select

I want to execute a function depending on which option in a dropdown menu is selected. For now I just wrote document.write() function to test if anything is happening.

However, nothing is printing, and the code is not working as I wanted.

```html
<h>Would you like to see count values per hour or minute?</h><br>
<Select id="Selector">
   <option value="hr">Hour</option>
   <option value="min">Minute</option>
</Select>
<script>
  if (document.getElementById('Selector').value == "min") {
    document.write("Hello World!");
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

For this, you will need an `onchange` listener, so every time the user changes the value on the select, it call that listener function and do something that you need. In my example below, I just change the document `background`, but it is sufficient to you get the logic, right?

```html
<h>Would you like to see count values per hour or minute?</h><br>
<Select id="Selector">
   <option value="hr">Hour</option>
   <option value="min">Minute</option>
</Select>
<script>
  document.getElementById("Selector").onchange = changeListener;
  
  function changeListener(){
  var value = this.value
    console.log(value);
    
    if (value == "min"){
      document.body.style.background = "red";
    }else if (value == "hr"){
      document.body.style.background = "blue";
    }
    
  }

</script>
```

**NOTE**: `onchange` is only triggered when the value changes, if the same value is selected, it doesn't trigger, so the function won't be called. To avoid this, take a look about other listeners, such as `onclick` or `onfocus` or `onblur`

Answer (score 4):

you can use onchange event to refer your function on selection like

```
<Select id="Selector" onchange="myFunction()">


function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("Selector").value;
   if(x==='min')
   document.write("Hello World!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach `onchange` event listener to your `select` element. http://jsfiddle.net/gj2n6rux/2/